Conditional Formatting (does not contain mulitple)
Help - how would I do conditional formatting formula to highlight entire row, where one column does not contain ULTD. OR UUS.
the following will work just using one criteria and only highlight rows where column E does not have ULD in the text, but struggling with how I string in UUS. and potentially other does not contain wildcard text
=ISERROR(SEARCH("*uld.*",$E10))


Try something like this =ISERR(SEARCH("*"&HSTACK("ultd.","uus.")&"*",$E10))

I believe you are looking for this formula:
=ISERROR(SEARCH("*uld.*",$E10)*SEARCH("*uus*",$E10))

When cell "$E10" neither looks like "uld.", neither like "uus", the value will be a natural number (not an error).
